# Ubuntu on dual boot messed up my partitions

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I have windows 10 on C: drive and I installed ubuntu 14.04 on D: on the 30.51 GB partition and Ubuntu 16.04 on 7.92GB partition.

But both my ubuntu are always crashing and I want to delete and install again. The problem is that now I cant delete both partitions because they only show the "help" option.

How the hell do I delete this? I have no idea. They say they are primary partitions.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried booting from a Linux USB Stick or CD and managing the disks from there?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will primarily try to format its OS under an **ext4** partition. This is **not** supported in windows and therefore you cannot access them.

There are a varity of 3rd Party tools availalbe such as [Mini Tool](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) which will aid you in completing this task in Windows.

Personally I would find the easiest option is to use a Live Linux USB in order to format the drive from Linux.